# Weinre Target Not Connected after page change

Tags: android, cordova, remote-debugging, phonegap-build, weinre

I'm using Weinre to Debug my PhoneGap App locally. I've enabled Debug on Adobe Build, and when I run the App, I am able to connect and debug using the Weinre interface:

[image: Able to Connect]

Everything works great until I navigate to a new page in my app. Then, I am disconnected, and can no longer debug:

[image: Not Able to Connect]

Can anyone offer any guidance, or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's just the way it works.  weinre runs in "user land" - that is, as a live thing inside your page.  So, when you replace the page with a different page, weinre won't be running on that new page, unless you've also instrumented that page to use weinre.

Please see the [latest weinre docs](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) for tips about using other debuggers, which might work out better for you.

Comment: I'm no longer working on this project, but for future readers of this, I do not believe this is the issue. It was very hit or miss as to when Weinre would allow debugging on different pages. Some days I tested it would every single time, but others it would 1 out of 10 times.